# Use variable on the mysql like sentence on laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql-like, query-builder

`$key` was a variable can be empty or something.

```
var key='"<?php echo $_REQUEST['key']; ?>"';
```

then send to the ajax by data

```
"ajax": {

          "url": "{{asset("try")}}",
          "type": 'POST',
          "dataType": 'json',
          "async": true,
          "data": {
             key : key,
            },
}
```

the try Controller

```
public function try(Request $request){
    $key=$request->key;

    DB::query()
    ->select('A.id','A.upper_p_id','A.key')
    ->from('users as A')
    ->leftjoin('products as B', function($join) {
        $join->on('A.ID', '=', 'B.p_id');
      })
    ->groupBy('A.id','A.upper_p_id','A.key')
    ->where('A.key', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%');
    ->get()

    return $result;
}
```

I got the error expression from the queries debug tool?

```
LIKE '%\"\"%'
```

But if I use

```
  ->where('A.n_geography','LIKE', '%'.''.'%');
```

It is right sentence from the queries debug tool.

```
LIKE  '%%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well - you did put in the double quotes in the `key` variable...
So it's doing it correctly :-)

Comment: so ? how to fix?

Comment: Just look at this:
var key='"<?php echo $_REQUEST['key']; ?>"';

you added double quotes IN the string...

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent SQL injection it is better not to concatenate the value directly but pass it as a param so try this:

```
$key = $request->key;

...
->whereRaw('A.key like ?', ['%' . $key . '%']);
```

And in your JS:

```
var key='<?php echo $_REQUEST['key']; ?>';
```

Comment: I use laravel controller. when I  use your suggestion. I got  the error :syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%?%

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get key from request, you ideally should no use $_GET o $_POST.

```
public function getData(Request $request){
    $key = $request->key;

    $records = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.p_id')
    ->groupBy('users.id','users.upper_p_id','users.key')
    ->where('users.key', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%')
    ->select('users.id','users.upper_p_id','users.key')
    ->get();

    return response()->json($records, 200);

}
```

However if the `key` variable is a javascript variable, then you can not directly use in controller. You need to pass it somehow in route param or using ajax request.

Secondly if you can add conditional `when` that if $key is present then only do a where clause :

```
public function getData(Request $request){
    $key = $request->key;

    $records = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.p_id')
    ->groupBy('users.id','users.upper_p_id','users.key')
    ->when($key, function($q) use($key){
        return $q->where('users.key', 'LIKE', '%'.$key.'%');
    })
    ->select('users.id','users.upper_p_id','users.key')
    ->get();

    return response()->json($records, 200);

}
```

Comment: I get the key from the $_request (it's a get) then send to the ajax request ... it still has the /"/"  .no fix it~

Answer (score 0):

You're double quoting `key`. The suggested way to share PHP variables as JS variables is to JSON encode them for example:

```
var key= {!! json_encode(request()->input('key')) !!};
```

Note that there are no additional quotes necessary in the JS code because valid JSON is also a valid JS variable.

Also note that since you are using Laravel it is recommended you use blade markup and the `request()` helper for accessing the request parameters